# Mailchimp Restful API 3.0 in Node.js always Resource not Found

Tags: node.js, http, request, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to hit one of the mailchimp's api, but for somehow I always get

```
   {
  "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
  "title": "Resource Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The requested resource could not be found.",
  "instance": ""
}
```

I'm using request library to make the request and see the code below

```
var uniqueListId = "XXXX";
var apiKey = "XXX";

  .post(function(req, res) {
      var email = req.body.email;
      var status = "subscribed";

      request({
        url: 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + uniqueListId + '/members',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'randomUser ' + apiKey,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
          email_address: email,
          status: status
        }
      }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(response.statusCode, body);
        }
      });
    });
```

For the sake of clarity, this is the documentation that I'm referring to http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/

Is it because of my req.body data?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @TooMuchPete, The same issue happened with me and scratched my head for a whole day to solve that issue, and finally, I've found that Audience Id`list_id` is wrong.

we need to pick the one which is located under the **AudienceTab > ViewContacts > Settings > Audience and Defaults > Audience ID**, but unfortunately, I have picked the one which is showing in the URL.

Comment: Dang it this tripped me up for 2 days...thanks for this answer! If any mail chimp devs are reading this...improve your error messaging.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly confusing mailchimp's web_id with list_id. The list_id is the one you need for the API, the web_id is the one you see in the url when you open your list.
I have absolutely no idea why mailchimp uses 2 different ids, nor why they don't seem to put it forward in any of their developer documentation.

Below is an article which explains how to find it - basically you go to your list -> settings tab -> list name and defaults.

https://3by400.com/get-support/3by400-knowledgebase?view=kb&kbartid=6

Comment: This bad design decision of mailchimp has cost me 15 minutes. Not more than that thanks to @Petrov.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 404 it's because the URL you're hitting doesn't refer to an actual resource. Probably `uniqueListId` is either empty or not the right ID.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Postman chrome add-on app to play with the requests and posts - you could also use it to generate sample code, in most languages. It is great for debugging.

After using it, I found that your request options should look something like:

```
let requestOptions =  { 
    hostname: 'us14.api.mailchimp.com',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/3.0/lists' + listId,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'User ' + config.mailChimp.apiKey,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}
```